# Best type of graph to show a relationship between a dependent variable that is continuous and an independent variable that is categorical?

Tags: r, regression

I am looking for a type of graph to show the relationship between a dependent variable (Number of Likes) and an Independent variable (Genre of Video)

my data looks something like this:

| Genre_of_Video | Number_Likes |
| --- | --- |
| Comedy | 500 |
| Comedy | 240 |
| Comedy | 250 |
| Romance | 120 |
| Thriller | 568 |
| Emotional | 320 |

My data is quite big and there is more than 2 categories in the dependent variable.
I tried to create a linear regression graph using this:

```
ggplot(youtubevideos, aes(x= Genre_of_Video, y = Number_Likes)) + geom_point()
```

but it just shows straight lines. What type of graph should I then use to show the relationship?

Comment: violin or boxplot maybe?

Comment: How do i then explain the relationship of the 2 variables with boxplot?

Comment: Linear regression makes only sense if both your independent and dependent variable are at least ordered (but should actually be continuous)... there is no inherent order in movie genres thou... Depending on the kind of data you have I 'd use ANOVA or some non parametric test

Comment: But if I have to translate them into a graph, is it possible?

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484299/how-to-check-the-correlation-between-categorical-and-numeric-independent-variabl

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of groups you have and the type of comparison you want to make, there could be several plots that could be used.

If you go in the following website, you can find several plots for specific problematic.
Go into "Num & Cat" section and you can visualize all descriptive plots.

*https://www.data-to-viz.com/*